# For schemaless db like mongodb How can I skip MODEL part for MVC or MVT for any framework. Especially DJANJO

Tags: django, mongodb, schemaless

Mongodb is a schemaless concept. So for django or any other framework, can i skip design MODEL part(MVC or MVT) in advanced. advice me

As Mongodb is schemaless, so I want to edit my db according to my requirement. Thats the reason i  choose MongoDB. In advanced if i design database blueprint (Model) then whats the use. I am new So please advice me what should I do in this condition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, models are not required in Django. There are some wrappers or libraries for mongodb in Django, you can checkout [django-mongodb-engine](https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).